# Jquery change() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

Why is this not alerting the var valueFirst content?

My Jquery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( ".target" ).change(function() {
    var valueFirst = $( ".target" ).val();
  });
  alert (valueFirst)
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<form>
  <select class="target">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I expect you forgotten the document ready.

Comment: Depends if the JS is at the start or at the end of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to change a variable and access it outside the main selector, you must define it at the level you wish to access it from:

```js
var valueFirst = '';

$( ".target" ).change(function() {
    valueFirst = $( ".target" ).val();
});

$('button').click(function() {
    alert (valueFirst)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="target">
  <option selected value="">-- Choose One --</option>
  <option>Foo</option>
  <option>Bar</option>
</select>

<button>Get valueFirst Value</button>
```

If you are looking to just access the variable from within the change function, then the following would work for you

```js
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
    var valueFirst = $( ".target" ).val();
    alert (valueFirst)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="target">
  <option selected value="">-- Choose One --</option>
  <option>Foo</option>
  <option>Bar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The alert isn't in the callback. Where it is, the variable is neither defined nor filled. Change your code to

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  var valueFirst = $( ".target" ).val();
  alert (valueFirst)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, because you initialise your variable INSIDE a function hence the ALERT cannot reach it.

TO be able to use it initiate it outiside like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var valueFirst;
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  valueFirst = $( ".target" ).val();
    });
  alert (valueFirst)
</script>
```

But to be alerted when the function is fired, put the alert inside the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  var valueFirst = $( ".target" ).val();
  alert (valueFirst)
});

</script>
```

Regarding Comment:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pp2135oc/6/)

You forgot to include Jquery, and your code must be inside the document.ready handler.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.target').change(function() {
  valueFirst = $( ".target" ).val();
  alert (valueFirst);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for all :).. did what you said and yet no alret  see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/pp2135oc/

Comment: @EyalLivne You forgot to include jquery in your fiddle and possible in your code. See edit in a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

valueFirst is out of the scope for change function

```
 $( ".target" ).change(function() {
          var valueFirst = $( ".target" ).val();
          alert (valueFirst);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add you alert inside the change function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( ".target" ).change(function(){ 
 var valueFirst = $( ".target" ).val(); 
 alert (valueFirst)
});  </script>
```